# Testing problem with `jest` snapshots and api testing

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, ts-jest

### I'm using `react-native` with `typescript` and I failed at testing with `jest` snapshots. I think problem is in calling API in component.

`errors log`

```
● renders correctly

    TypeError: (0 , _services.useGetUserDataQuery) is not a function

      14 |   });
      15 |
    > 16 |   const { data: userData } = useGetUserDataQuery();
         |                              ^
      17 |   const { data: contact } = useGetOfficeDataQuery(userData?.office_id);
      18 |
      19 |   const OfficeAdressMap =

      at ContactAdressMapBackground (src/components/ContactAdressMapBackground.tsx:16:30)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6016:18)
      at mountIndeterminateComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8744:13)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:9966:16)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13800:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13728:5)
      at renderRootSync (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13691:7)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:13404:18)
      at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:2537:26
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:468:12)

  console.error
    The above error occurred in the <ContactAdressMapBackground> component:

        at ContactAdressMapBackground (C:\projects\test\src\components\ContactAdressMapBackground.tsx:12:22)

    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
    Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.

      at logCapturedError (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:10989:23)
      at update.callback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11022:5)
      at callCallback (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3662:12)
      at commitUpdateQueue (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:3683:9)
      at commitLifeCycles (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11855:11)
      at commitLayoutEffects (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:14443:7)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackProd (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:11308:10)
```

---

`ContactAdressMapBackground-test.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import ContactAdressMapBackground from '../ContactAdressMapBackground';

jest.mock('../../services', async () => ({
  useUserDataQuery: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('fc5bf89b-9df8-4631-8f56-d08bb6a8d720')
}));

jest.mock('react-redux', () => ({
  useDispatch: jest.fn()
}));

// it('api test case', async function () {
//   const response = await
//   console.warn(response)
//   expect(response.office_id).toBe('fc5bf89b-9df8-4631-8f56-d08bb6a8d720')
// })


test('renders correctly', async () => {
  const tree = await renderer.create(<ContactAdressMapBackground />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

---

`ContactAdressMapBackground.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import Colors from '@constants/Colors';
import { View, Text, ContactIcon } from '@components/Themed';
import { useFonts } from '@use-expo/font';
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
import { useGetOfficeDataQuery, useGetUserDataQuery } from '../services';
import { t } from 'i18n-js';

const ContactAdressMapBackground = () => {
  const [isLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Poppins-Regular': require('../../assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.otf')
  });

  const { data: userData } = useGetUserDataQuery();
  const { data: contact } = useGetOfficeDataQuery(userData?.office_id);

  const OfficeAdressMap =
    'https://www.google.com/maps/search/?api=1&query=' +
    `${contact?.street} ${contact?.house_number} ${contact?.room_number} ${contact?.zip_code} ${contact?.city}`;

  if (!isLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('../../assets/images/map.png')}
          style={styles.map}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.mapAlignTextIcon}
            onPress={() => {
              Linking.openURL(OfficeAdressMap);
            }}
          >
            <View style={styles.icons}>
              <ContactIcon name="map-marker-outline" />
            </View>
            <Text style={styles.mapText}>{t('contact.showOnMap')}</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export default ContactAdressMapBackground;

[... there are styles]
```

---

`services.ts` from where I call external API

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { RootState } from '../src/redux/store';

export interface UserResponse {
  data: {
    access_token: string;
    expires_in: number;
    refresh_token: string;
    role: string;
  };
}

export interface LoginRequest {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

const device_id = '38bd41ec-f795-4cb6-3ae7-4c30b873';

export const callApi = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'path to api',
    prepareHeaders: (headers, { getState }) => {
      const token = (getState() as RootState).auth.access_token;

      if (device_id) {
        headers.set('Device_Id', device_id);
        headers.set('Authorization', `${token}`);
      }
      return headers;
    }
  }),
  endpoints: builder => ({
    login: builder.mutation<UserResponse, LoginRequest>({
      query: data => ({
        url: '/sessions',
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
      })
    }),
    getUserData: builder.query({
      query: (arg:void) => ({ url: `users/me/`, body: arg })
    }),
    getOfficeData: builder.query({
      query: (office_id: string) => ({ url: `office_contacts/${office_id}` })
    }),
  })
});

export const { useLoginMutation, useGetOfficeDataQuery, useGetUserDataQuery } =
  callApi;
```

Problem is that I can't figured out how to test components with api requests. I tested out with snapshot simple components but with more complex docs are unreadable.
Clue is that I want to pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

You are mocking `useUserDataQuery` instead of `useGetUserDataQuery`, so `useGetUserDataQuery` is not considered a function for jest